# Achieving consistent block sizing in python raw file IO

Tags: python, file-io, io, raw, raw-file

#### Question up front:

Is there a pythonic way in the standard library for parsing raw binary files using `for ... in ...` syntax  (i.e., `__iter__`/`__next__`)  that yields blocks that respect the `buffersize` parameter, *without* having to subclass `IOBase` or its child classes?

#### Detailed explanation

I'd like to open a raw file for parsing, making use of the `for ... in ...` syntax, and I'd like that syntax to yield predictably shaped objects.  This wasn't happening as expected for a problem I was working on, so I tried the following test (`import numpy as np` required):

```
In [271]: with open('tinytest.dat', 'wb') as f:
     ...:     f.write(np.random.randint(0, 256, 16384, dtype=np.uint8).tobytes())
     ...:

In [272]: np.array([len(b) for b in open('tinytest.dat', 'rb', 16)])
Out[272]:
array([  13,  138,  196,  263,  719,   98,  476,    3,  266,   63,   51,
    241,  472,   75,  120,  137,   14,  342,  148,  399,  366,  360,
     41,    9,  141,  282,    7,  159,  341,  355,  470,  427,  214,
     42, 1095,   84,  284,  366,  117,  187,  188,   54,  611,  246,
    743,  194,   11,   38,  196, 1368,    4,   21,  442,  169,   22,
    207,  226,  227,  193,  677,  174,  110,  273,   52,  357])
```

I could not understand why this random behavior was arising, and why it was not respecting the `buffersize` argument.  Using `read1` gave the expected number of bytes:

```
In [273]: with open('tinytest.dat', 'rb', 16) as f:
     ...:     b = f.read1()
     ...:     print(len(b))
     ...:     print(b)
     ...:
16
b'M\xfb\xea\xc0X\xd4U%3\xad\xc9u\n\x0f8}'
```

And  there it is: A newline near the end of the first block.

```
In [274]: with open('tinytest.dat', 'rb', 2048) as f:
     ...:     print(f.readline())
     ...:
b'M\xfb\xea\xc0X\xd4U%3\xad\xc9u\n'
```

Sure enough, `readline` was being called to produce each block of the file, and it was tripping up on the newline value (corresponding to 10).  I verified this reading through the code, lines in the [definition of IOBase](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/dedc2cd5f02a2e2fc2c995a36a3dccf9d93856bb/Lib/_pyio.py#L571):

```
571    def __next__(self):
572    line = self.readline()
573    if not line:
574        raise StopIteration
575    return line
```

So my question is this: is there some more pythonic way to achieve `buffersize`-respecting raw file behavior that allows `for ... in ...` syntax, *without* having to subclass `IOBase` or its child classes (and thus, not being part of the standard library)?   If not, does this unexpected behavior warrant a PEP? (Or does it warrant learning to expect the behavior?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior isn't unexpected, it is documented that all objects derived from `IOBase` iterate over *lines*. The only thing that changes between binary vs text mode is how a line terminator is defined, it is always defined as `b"\n"` in binary mode.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#i-o-base-classes):

> IOBase (and its subclasses) supports the iterator protocol, meaning
> that an IOBase object can be iterated over yielding the lines in a
> stream. Lines are defined slightly differently depending on whether
> the stream is a binary stream (yielding bytes), or a text stream
> (yielding character strings). See `readline()` below.

The problem is that there used to historically be ambiguity between text and binary data in the type system, this was a major motivating factor of the Python 2 -> 3 transition breaking backwards-compatibility.

I think it would certainly be *reasonable* to have the iterator protocol respect the buffer size for file objects opened in binary mode in Python 3. Why it was decided to keep the old behavior is something I can only speculate about.

In any case, you should just define your own iterator, that is common in Python. Iterators are a basic building block, like built-in types.

You can actually use the 2-argument `iter(callable, sentinel)` form to construct a super basic wrapper:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def iter_blocks(f, n):
...     return iter(partial(f.read, n), b'')
...
>>> np.array([len(b) for b in iter_blocks(open('tinytest.dat', 'rb'), 16)])
array([16, 16, 16, ..., 16, 16, 16])
```

Of course, you could have just used a generator:

```
def iter_blocks(bin_file, n):
    result = bin_file.read(n)
    while result:
        yield result
        result = bin_file.read(n)
```

There are tons of ways of approaching this. Again, iterators are *a core type* for writing idiomatic Python.

Python is a pretty dyanamic language, and "duck typing" is the name of the game. Generally, your first instinct shouldn't be "how to subclass some built-in type to extend functionality". I mean, often that is *possible*, but you'll find that there are a lot of language features geared towards not having to do that, and often, it is simply better expressed that way to begin with, at least, usually to my eyes.

Comment: 'Generally, your first instinct shouldn't be "how to subclass some built-in type to extend functionality".'  This is very helpful, thanks.